# Vowpal Wabbit -ngrams in selected Namespace

Tags: n-gram, vowpalwabbit

I have a sample.

text1_Namespace1: text

text2_Namespace2: text2

I want to make a new feature only from the Namespace1 text1 using the n-gram and not create other interactions in text2

Can the VW selectively generate ngrams for certain Namespace1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `vw -h` says, you can generate n-grams for a single namespace 'foo' using `--ngram fN` (e.g. `--ngram f2` for bigrams, `--ngram f3` for trigrams etc).
Note that in VW, only the first character of a namespace name is significant for the purpose of namespace interactions and generating ngrams. The general advice is to use either one-character namespace names or make sure that each namespace starts with a different character.

Comment: Thank you.
Everything works, even here such a design:
vw -d test.data --loss_function logistic --skips b2 --ngram b2 --ngram g2
 --skips g1

Comment: I am happy it helped. The StackOverflow way of say it works/thanks is to accept the answer (green tick).

Answer (score 0):

Works! Even here such a design:

vw -d test.data --loss_function logistic --skips b2 --ngram b2 --ngram g2 --skips g1